# О компании (фирме): производительная или производственная

Tags: выбор-слов

Нашёл такой абзац в новостях:

> Китайская **производительная компания** Lenovo, занимающаяся сборкой
>   персональных компьютеров и смартфонов, потерпело первые финансовые
>   убытки в рамках третьего квартала текущего года впервые за шестилетний
>   период.

Однако комбинация

```
производительная компания
```

резанула слух. Может быть *производительный компьютер*, но компания, в моём понимании, может быть лишь *производственная*. Рассудите, пожалуйста.

Comment: _Однако комбинация

**производительная компания**

резанула слух. Может быть производительный компьютер, но компания, в моём понимании, может быть лишь производственная._ === **По-моему, правильно понимаете**.

Comment: А "компания потерпело" не резануло?

Comment: @LazyBadger На заметил( В общем происхождение текста понятно - малограмотный рерайт из другого источника.

Answer (score 2):

**Слово «производительный» имеет более широкое значение  по сравнению со словом «производственный».**

Производить – производ/ительн/ый (создающий что-либо ценное).

Производить – производ/ство – производ/ств/енн/ый (связанный непосредственно с производством).

С одной стороны, производительная компания может **заниматься производством**, то есть являться производственной компанией, например: Китайская производительная компания предлагает климатическое оборудование. Это компания-производитель оборудования.

С другой стороны, это может быть **комплексная деятельность,** например:  Компания занимается оптовыми поставками товаров из Китая. Мы имеем собственную производственную компанию, выпускающую автомобильные комплекты безопасности и т.д.  Помимо товаров, мы так же предлагаем огромный перечень услуг связанных непосредственно с ведением бизнеса с Китаем.

Также производительная компания может заниматься **изготовлением оборудования для производства**, например: Китайская производительная компания изготовляет оборудование для производства медицинских товаров.

**Из словаря**

ПРОИЗВОДИТЕЛЬНЫЙ, Создающий, производящий что-л. ценное; продуктивный. П. труд. П. капитал (капитал, функционирующий в производственном процессе в целях создания прибавочной стоимости). П-ые силы (средства для производства материальных благ и люди, приводящие в движение эти средства и осуществляющие производство материальных благ).

ПРОИЗВОДСТВО, 2. То, что производится, изготовляется; продукция. Прирост производства составляет пятнадцать процентов. 3. Работа по непосредственному изготовлению продукции; само предприятие (фабрика, завод и т.п.), на котором производится такая работа. Перейти из управления на п. Работать на производстве. Учиться без отрыва от производства. Начальник производства.